# Redis - Max channels/topics for pub/sub

Tags: redis

I am trying to create chat rooms app and use redis pub/sub broadcasting messages across subscribers. Each meeting room is 1 channel. The problem is I can have infinite number of channels over time.

- Is there any limit for max number of channels I can have in redis?
- Is there any way to auto expire/delete channels which have not received any messages for publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any limit for max number of channels I can have in redis?

Redis doesn't set any limit on the number of channels. Channels are saved into a hash, whose size is of type `long`. So in theory, the limit is `2**63` on a 64 bits machine. However, since your memory is limited, you cannot reach the limit. In a word, practically, there's no limit.

> Is there any way to auto expire/delete channels which have not received any messages for publishing?

There's no way to do that. Redis deletes a channel, only when all clients of the channel have unsubscribed it, i.e. when a channel has no subscribers, Redis remove the channel automatically. If there's at least one client subscribing it, Redis keep the channel even if there's no message published to it.

Comment: "There's no way to do that. Redis deletes a channel, only when all clients of the channel have unsubscribed it, i.e. when a channel has no subscribers, Redis remove the channel automatically. If there's at least one client subscribing it, Redis keep the channel even if there's no message published to it." - is there any doc link you could share for this?

Comment: @RamPrakash I'm not sure if there's any document about that. However, the source code explains everything :) Channel works as Redis `LIST`, when you popped all items in LIST, Redis removes the LIST automatically. Similarly, when all clients unsubscribed the channel, Redis removes the channel automatically.